# Broadcastreceiver intent filters

Tags: android, intentfilter

Which intent filter should I use in a broadcast receiver when I want that a service is running every 5 minutes, without the need of a reboot?

Comment: If I understand you goal right, you should better use AlarmManager http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: Does that work without a need that the app is running?

Comment: Yes it works as Android service. I mean on OS level.

Comment: Could you please give an example? I can't understand it when I searched at Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of using AlarmManager

set alarm

```
private void setAlarm(Context ctx, long timeToRestoreLivesInMillis) {
        int perion = 1000;
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Intent i = new Intent(ctx, OnAlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, 0, i, 0);

        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, period, pi);
}
```

and some receiver which will receive an Intent

```
public class OnAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

and don't forget to register receiver in `Manifest.xml`

```
<receiver
    android:name=".utils.OnAlarmReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false" >
</receiver>
```

read docs for methods explanation, I have worked with it long time ago.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpfull. Do I need to put something in my manifest? Wich intent-filter?

Comment: Oke, and one last question, where do I need to call the function setAlarm? In the mainactivity?